# Replacement ceiling light wont turn off

Tags: wiring

I know i will be told i should have gone to an electrician but this seemed easy enough.

Photo attached, the light i took down had one brown and one blue wire, the light i replaced it with had one brown and one blue. All i did was a direct swap, took a photo and just made sure it matched exactly.

Now my hall light switch will need replacing as it wont turn off, the new light i have fitted has space for four bulbs, i can get it working with two but when i go to three the fuse box switches off with a loud pop, the bulb has black soot at the cap and is broken.

I am thinking the new light i bought has bad wiring in it considering i have just copied everything exactly.

Thoughts?[image: Light Fitting]

Comment: Do you still have the old light? What happens when you temporarily reinstall the old light?

Comment: Is the new light the same voltage as the original. The US uses 120v lighting but based on the colors and terminal block o would guess you are 240v if you happened to get a 120v fixture I would expect a pop on 240v unless it happened to have a universal power supply 100-277v range.